# Quelles sont les différentes nuances du mot « stress » ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot

Au cours d'une discussion avec des amis, je me suis aperçu que le mot « stress » est très (trop) souvent utilisé.

J'imagine que ce terme est une catégorie de haut niveau, et que par paresse je n'utilise que « stress » pour tout et n'importe quoi.

- Utilisez-vous tous ces mêmes raccourcis ?
- Pouvez-vous m'aider à trouver des équivalents ou des nuances ?

Comment: Aurais-tu quelques exemples ? J'ai du mal à comprendre le problème.

Comment: @M'vy en général, on utilise "stress" à tout va : _Tu ne peux pas savoir quel stress je subis au bureau_, même pour de simples contrariétes, alors qu'aucun diagnostic médical de stress n'a été posé. Autre utilisation plus éloignée: _Y'a un stress_ pour _Il y a quelque chose qui ne va pas_.

Comment: @M'vy voici des exemples: J'ai une réunion qualité demain, ça me « stress » ! Je suis « stressé » car j'ai arrêté de fumer ! Mon téléphone coupe tout le temps, c'est stressant !

Comment: Je suis le seul à prendre ça comme un verbe et à conjuguer en accordance ? Ça me stresse, ces `-ss` sans rien au bout.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks je suis d'accord avec vous, mais je ne peux plus éditer mon commentaire ;) En revanche je ne comprend pas le commentaire à propos du guillemet en début de ligne...

Comment: @chepseskaf j'ai remplacé les espaces entre le mot et les guillements qui l'entourent par des espaces dites *insécables*, ce qui signifie qu'on ne peut pas couper la phrase à cet endroit là (revenir à la ligne). Avant cette modification (très mineure), sur certains affichages (comme chez moi), la ligne se finissait avec le mot "stress", et la ligne suivante commençait par le guillemet fermant ("»"), ce qui est typographiquement affreux ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depuis quelques années en France le stress, en particulier le stress au travail, est un sujet d'actualité. De plus, c'est une notion difficile à cerner parce que très subjective. Cela peut expliquer pourquoi le mot est employé à toutes les sauces (pas nécessairement à tort mais c'est une autre histoire).

Dans le milieu du travail, la définition admise est la suivante ([source INRS](http://www.inrs.fr/risques/stress/ce-qu-il-faut-retenir.html)):

> Le stress « survient lorsqu'il y a déséquilibre entre la perception
>   qu'une personne a des contraintes que lui impose son environnement et
>   la perception qu'elle a de ses propres ressources pour y faire face.
>   Bien que le processus d'évaluation des contraintes et des ressources
>   soit d'ordre psychologique, les effets du stress ne sont pas
>   uniquement de nature psychologique. Il affecte également la santé
>   physique, le bien-être et la productivité ».

Selon les contextes on peut parler de *pression* ou plus formellement de *risques psychosociaux*, abrégés en *RPS*.

Comment: Je me demande quand _stress_ remplacera _pression_ dans les bars. _Roger, un stress, s'il-te-plaît !_

Comment: [Je ne sais pas](http://www.drinkswap.com/absolut-stress.htm).

Answer (score 2):

A mon (humble) avis, on utilise stress lorsque l'on ressent un malaise dû à une pression réelle ou supposée sur sa vie (professionnelle ou personnelle).

Lorsque ce stress se transforme en un mal "validé" médicalement, on a tendance à utiliser d'autres termes (anxiété ou autre).

Ainsi, on dira "mon patron me stresse" ou bien "je continue a fumer, cela me dé-stress". On dira aussi "mon médecin m'a dit d'être moins stressé" si il s'agit de belles paroles sans conséquences médicamenteuses, alors qu'on dira "je prends des médicaments pour soigner mon anxiété" (là on ne parle plus de stress) car on parle d'un mal précis et connu.

Comment: Le stress est pour moi un cause (ni nécessaire, ni toujours suffisante), l'anxiété, la dépression, ... sont les conséquences.

Answer (score 1):

On peut trouver de synonymes de « stress »:  « angoisse », « agression », « choc » ou « tension »

Des synonymes du verbe « stresser »: « agresser », « angoisser » ou « apeurer ».

C'est vrai que le « stress » est utilisé tout le temps même pour désigner des petits tracas de la vie. On a du mal à remplacer « stress » par un autre mot sans que ce soit lourd de sens.

Exemple: « L'exam de philo de demain me stresse » devient « L'exam de philo de demain m'angoisse ». On n'est plus dans la petite anxiété d'un exam, cf. la définition de [CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/angoisse):

> Inquiétude intense, liée à une situation d'attente, de doute, de solitude et qui fait pressentir des malheurs ou des souffrances graves devant lesquels on se sent impuissant.

Answer (score 0):

le stress au travail est une catégorie particulière de stress . voir à ce sujet : La prévention du stress au travail :  http://www.officiel-prevention.com/protections-collectives-organisation-ergonomie/psychologie-du-travail/detail_dossier_CHSCT.php?rub=38&ssrub=163&dossid=266

Comment: Pouvez-vous résumer le contenu du lien ? En particulier, à part une cause particulière, quelles nuances est-ce que le *stress au travail* a particulièrement ?